# Custom Vector class, return vector like an array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, templates, vector

I'm trying to create a custom vector class and overloading all operators. consider the following code:

```
  template <class T>
  class vector{

     private:
     T * arrayOfObj;
     // other class members

    public:

     Vector(){
      arrayOfObj = new T[100];
     }
     vector(int size); 
     // other functions for vector class, overloaded [], =, etc.
    }
```

in another class, I need to return the vector but with a pointer like when we return an array:

```
   #include "B.h"
   class c {

     vector<B> vect;

     public:
     B * getArray(){
       return vect;
     }
```

First, is it possible to retrun a vector like an array?
Also, if I wanted to access the dynamic array encapsulated inside the vector class without using a public function to return the array, how should be my approach?

Comment: *I'm trying to create a custom vector class* -- [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbd9033d9c94f6b3).  Learn from a working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First, is it possible to retrun a vector like an array?

Sure, that's what [`std::vector::data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) does. It's as simple as doing `return arrayOfObj;` in whatever method or operator overload.

> Also, if I wanted to access the dynamic array encapsulated inside the vector class without using a public function to return the array, how should be my approach?

Not possible. Either you allow access to your internal storage via a public function or you don't allow that, your choice. In `c::getArray()` you could also copy all elements of `vect` into a new array - this way noone will alter `vect` from the outside and you don't have to provide access to internal storage of `vector` class.

There is also `friend` mechanism that allows one function or class to access private members of another class, but it's usually worse than public access[.](https://ih0.redbubble.net/image.31410519.6760/flat,800x800,075,t.u4.jpg)